# ARMA Models with Trend Question

Tags: time-series, arima, trend, differencing

I am looking to build an ARMA model for a time series with a significant trend component.

Let's assume for the purposes of this question that I don't want to build an ARIMA model.  (The reason has to do with how I am looking to incorporate exogenous features into the model.)

I can make the series stationary with first differencing.  I build an ARMA model with the first differenced result.  I use the at level data going into the model and Hyndman's equations to convert the resulting first differenced forecast into an at-level result.

Do I need to be concerned that this approach will ignore the trend I observed in my initial data?

Comment: Hi: since you're doing first differencing, that means that you are assuming that the series is difference stationary. There's also the concept of trend stationarity and choosing between which of these ( difference or trend ) is the case is kind of a whole literature in itself. So, it's best to probably google for "trend stationary versus difference stationary". I'm sure that will bring up a lot of results.

Comment: I second mlofton. If the trend is deterministic, differencing the series will result in problems collectively known as *overdifferencing*. If the trend is stochastic (there is a unit root), only then is differencing warranted. By the way, what are Hyndman's equations?

Comment: Is there a test that will tell me whether my series is trend stationary vs difference stationary?

Richard, just referring to the material here: https://otexts.com/fpp2/stationarity.html